# JSPF is not loading lib of jar

Tags: java, plugins, classloader

I am using Java Simple Plugin Framework. I export a jar that has my plugin implementation. The implementation depends on a library, which I have as a jar. That jar gets exported within the lib directory of my jar, and added to the classpath of my jar.

But when I load my jar with JSPF, it fails with "NoClassDefFound" because it can't find the jar in the lib director of my jar.

My apologies if my approach off base; I just need to know how this is supposed to be done. How should I bundle my plugin implementation as a jar if it depends on another jar?

Answer (score 0):

I used JSPF and achieved this requirement  the following way:

place the library jar file in a folder called lib **outside** the plugin jar file. (So that 
the lib folder and the plugin jar file is in the same folder). Then I added lib/"name_of_libjar" to the classpath entry in the manifest.mf file of the plugin jar file (Which should be inside the plugin jar files META-INF folder), and it worked fine for me.